# spring batch admin stop button doesn't work

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I use spring batch admin to run spring-batch , everything's working properly except job "stop" button.
it leads to an empty page with this error code
**HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported**
I have no idea why it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in old spring batch forum,
I needed to add these filters in my web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>shallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```